# pull and push docker image to localhost via dind

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker

When build images in dind (docker in docker), the image is only accessible in dind.

```
$ docker run -d --name dind --privileged --net=host -v `pwd`:/app -w /app docker:stable-dind
fe66d6e7e5effcf15e439a332a2368fddab810e9bc8ac3445392c8e56b0aa38a

$ docker exec dind ls
Dockerfile

$ docker exec dind docker build -t demo .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  521.7kB
Step 1/24 : FROM alpine
...

$ docker exec dind docker images|grep demo
REPOSITORY                                              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
demo                                                    latest              a9dd4e725029        7 seconds ago       88.3MB

$ docker images |grep demo
<no result>
```

I can push the image to public or private docker registry server in `dind`, because they have IP or dns name to access. But how can I push the new image back to localhost (`the host running dind`)

Second, if I want to pull image from localhost in Dind, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I can answer my first question now.

```
$ docker exec dind docker save demo |docker load
2f7d711abbe9: Loading layer [==================================================>]  11.44MB/11.44MB
...
Loaded image: demo:latest

$ docker images |grep demo
demo                                                                              latest                  a9dd4e725029        8 minutes ago       88.3MB
```

Same size :-)

But still not sure how to pull image from localhost in Dind, any ideas?